# нужно сделать выборку со сравнением среднего

Tags: teradata

есть набор данных за несколько дней (несколько миллионов), вот пример структуры таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я хочу сделать выборку значений по последнему столбцу, если он превышает среднее значение других дней на N процентов. делаю так

```
select
имя,
оператор,
регион,
день7 * 1.5 as Сurrent_day
    from таблица
    where Сurrent_day is not null
    --and Сurrent_day > avg(день1 + день2 + день3 + день6)
    group by имя, оператор, регион, Сurrent_day
    ;
```

выборка делается, но когда делаю сравнение (убрать "--"), выходит ошибка. понятно, что названия условные

подскажите, пожалуйста, либо я что-то делаю не так, либо может какой-то другой вариант

Answer (score 1):

в общем, получилось, что вместо avg использовал простую математику

```
((день1 + день2 + день3 + день6) / 4) as avgd,
(день7 * 100 / avgd) as coff
```

и в условие

```
where coff > 150
```

как-то так))